# List view and list adapters for displaying json

Tags: android, listview, listadapter

I am trying to display the text from json in a list view. I got help for retrieving the json text from the following...
http://www.josecgomez.com/2010/04/30/android-accessing-restfull-web-services-using-json/comment-page-1/#comment-498....

But my problem is that i cant figure out how to display them in list view. I also want to get only some of the text from url(for example, alerttext and date). Can anyone help me in declaring the list adapter and list view in order to display the data in the way i want...
Plzzzz...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got the way to do it here...

http://www.josecgomez.com/2010/05/03/android-putting-custom-objects-in-listview/

Thanks to Jose for solving the problem. Hope this post will help some other amateur android developers like me... Kudos to Android development team...:-)