# How to populate the list view with data downloaded via JSON Web Services

Tags: android, json, listview, expandablelistview

I want to populate the listview with data (String only) downloaded via Web Services. Kindly provide the working code example.

Comment: have a look at this question can be similar and there is a link that will provide an example. The question is also a bit too big to cover can you show some code of what you are having at the moment some code etc...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2756780/list-view-and-list-adapters-for-displaying-json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

below link can help you

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/